# SQL Pivot Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

If you could please help with this. The code generates an error: 
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 236
The column 'Classification_Value_Id' was specified multiple times for 'piv1'.

I am doing this on SQL Server. The steps for the code is as follows:
1. Unpivot the data from the source table DB.[dbo].[Classification] into one column
2. Join this unpivoted data to a table called DB.dbo.[Classification_Value] to return/add the column 'cv.Classification_Name'  to the data set
3. Pivot this dataset (This is the part returning the error)

CODE:

```
SELECT
       activityCode
     , actjvPartnerRef
     , actMonth
     , actSalesChannel
     , addCBPCharge
     , agentId
     , appType
     , areaCode

--SELECT
--polRef,[Arrangement_Id],UnpivotedData.Classification_Value_Id,UnpivotedData.Classification_Scheme_Id,ColValues, ColNames,cv.Classification_Name

FROM
(
    SELECT top 10
           [polRef]
         , [Arrangement_Id]
         , [Classification_Scheme_Id]
         , [Classification_Value_Id]
       -- ,[Arrangement_Classification_Type_Id]
       -- ,[Effective_TimeStamp]
       -- ,[End_date]
         , CAST((ISNULL([character_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS character_measure
         , CAST((ISNULL([datetime_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS datetime_measure
         , CAST([decimal_measure] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS decimal_measure
         , CAST((ISNULL([integer_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS integer_measure
         , CAST((ISNULL([logical_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS logical_measure
         , CAST((ISNULL([charmax_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS charmax_measure
         , CAST((ISNULL([long_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS long_measure
      FROM DB.[dbo].[Classification] 
) AS SrcDataConverted

UNPIVOT
(
ColValues FOR ColNames IN
(
     character_measure
   , datetime_measure
   , decimal_measure
   , integer_measure
   , logical_measure
   , charmax_measure
   , long_measure
)
) AS UnpivotedData

LEFT JOIN DB.dbo.[Classification_Value] cv
ON  cv.[Classification_Scheme_Id] = UnpivotedData.[Classification_Scheme_Id]
AND cv.Classification_Value_Id = UnpivotedData.Classification_Value_Id

PIVOT
(MAX(ColValues) for Classification_Name in (
    activityCode
  , actjvPartnerRef
  , actMonth
  , actSalesChannel
  , addCBPCharge
  , agentId
  , appType
  , areaCode
)) AS piv1;
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StuarLC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314291/stuartlc):
An additional derived table needs to wrap the results of the UNPIVOT before commencing the re-PIVOT, as the join introduces a duplicated Classification_Value_Id and Classification_Scheme_id, which is needed for the join.

```
select 
       activityCode
     , actjvPartnerRef
     , actMonth
     , actSalesChannel
     , addCBPCharge
     , agentId
     , appType
     , areaCode
from (
   SELECT polRef
        , [Arrangement_Id]
        , UnpivotedData.Classification_Value_Id
        , UnpivotedData.Classification_Scheme_Id
        , ColValues
        , ColNames
        , Classification_Name
    FROM (
        SELECT [polRef]
             , [Arrangement_Id]
             , [Classification_Scheme_Id]
             , [Classification_Value_Id]
             , CAST((ISNULL([character_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS character_measure
             , CAST((ISNULL([datetime_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS datetime_measure
             , CAST([decimal_measure] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS decimal_measure
             , CAST((ISNULL([integer_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS integer_measure
             , CAST((ISNULL([logical_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS logical_measure
             , CAST((ISNULL([charmax_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS charmax_measure
             , CAST((ISNULL([long_measure],'')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS long_measure
          FROM DB.[dbo].[Classification] 
    ) AS SrcDataConverted
    UNPIVOT
    (
        ColValues FOR ColNames IN
        (
             character_measure
           , datetime_measure
           , decimal_measure
           , integer_measure
           , logical_measure
           , charmax_measure
           , long_measure
        )
    ) AS UnpivotedData
    LEFT JOIN 
        DB.dbo.[Classification_Value] cv
    ON  cv.[Classification_Scheme_Id] = UnpivotedData.[Classification_Scheme_Id]
    AND cv.Classification_Value_Id = UnpivotedData.Classification_Value_Id
) as src
PIVOT
(   
    MAX(ColValues) for Classification_Name in (
            activityCode
          , actjvPartnerRef
          , actMonth
          , actSalesChannel
          , addCBPCharge
          , agentId
          , appType
          , areaCode
    )
) AS piv1;
```

Comment: +1 - An additional derived table needs to wrap the results of the `UNPIVOT` before commencing the re-PIVOT, as the join introduces a duplicated `Classification_Value_Id` and `Classification_Scheme_id`, which is needed for the join. [SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2ac0/2)

Comment: @brett Thank you for your reply: the following errorcode: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'activityCode'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Invalid column name 'actjvPartnerRef'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'actMonth'.
.....
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 56
The column name "activityCode" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 57 ...

Comment: i have corrected my code as per the provided fiddle (thank you @StuartLC). i assumed you just took the version from his fiddle (which worked already).

Comment: @Aarion go here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2ac0/2 and then edit the schema. after you are finished, post the new url here

Comment: @StuartLC and Brett I have built the schema on sqlfiddle and uploaded the SQL code as well  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30da24

Comment: i put in the code (and renamed classification to Arrangement_Classification_CorrectType) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30da24/4 .
if you add some sample data, we could work out why it is not returning enough data.
by the way, there was a `top 10` in the original select which i have now removed. that may have been the cause of the missing data. check if it is still in the version you are using and try selecting without it

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30da24 - The code I am using is in this. It is returning data for some columns like polref but it looks like it is not pivoting the data .. The there should be one pol ref per row but the polref is coming in multiple columns .. so the data is not rolling up

Comment: that's the old url, please post the new one

Comment: @BrettSchneider - I have added the polref column to the SELECT statement in your code : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30da24/6

Comment: Is there a way I can add some data into SQLfiddle? WOuld it be an INSERT statement

Comment: you can include inserts on the left panel. when you rebuild your schema afterwards, the tables should contain data

Comment: @BrettSchneider - I have struggled to put data into the table: Arrangement_Classification_CorrectType .. there's one row in there. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71533

Comment: It is till the same - I tired adding more data but did not work:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b88e

Comment: the reason is that for the `Classification_Value_Id / Classification_Scheme_Id` combination coming in from the `unpivot`, there is no matching `[Classification_Value]`. hence when using `left join` you only get `null` for `Classification_Name`. when pivoting for `for Classification_Name in (activityCode, actjvPartnerRef, actMonth, actSalesChannel, addCBPCharge, agentId, appType, areaCode` you naturally get nothing.
also, the data provided only contains polRef as `Classification_Name`, so when pivoting for all those mentioned above will yield no data. the code is fine, your data does not match